# How to handle onKeyDown event on div in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, keypress

I'm trying to handle key event when load page component.
First, I have a router:

```
<Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
</Router>
```

In home component, I try to bind onKeyPress in div element but it's not work. I bind it on input element, it's worked.

```
return (
        <div onKeyDown={this.__handleKeyDown} className="container" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.backgroundbanner})` }}>
            <input
                className="hidden"
                onKeyDown={this.__handleKeyDown}
                ref={(input) => { this.dummyInput = input; }}
                />
            <div className="container-shadow">
                <h1 className="main-title">{this.state.title}</h1>
                <h3 className="main-description">{this.state.description}</h3>
                <ListMovie cursor={ cursor } />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

How to bind event onKeyDown on div element or how to bind key event when load a page component in Route. Because, input element can be out-focus and this key event cannot be excute.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason as to why it doesn't work is that the `div` element requires the `tabIndex` attribute in order to be focusable and to handle keyDown events.

```
<div tabIndex="1" onKeyDown={this.__handleKeyDown}></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Andrei, the simple solution :). It's worked.

Comment: You'll likely want to set to -1 since you're manipulating it programmatically.
https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex

Answer (score 6):

**Approach 1:**

For the event to trigger, your div needs to be selected. To do this you need to focus it in the componentDidMount event. And to do this you need a ref to your div.

Step 1: get a ref to your div

```
<div onKeyDown={this.__handleKeyDown} ref={(c) => {this.div = c;}}>
```

Step 2: Focus it on load

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.div.focus();
}
```

**Approach 2:**

Listen to events on the entire document

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
}
```

Comment: for me `this.ref.current.focus()`